# How to become a qualified Bodek Shaatnez

Tags: adult-learning, inspection, shaatnez

I would very much like to learn the laws and the practical checking of Shaatnez - how do I go about?

Comment: Try seeing if your local Shaatnez checker (if your community has one) is willing to teach you

Comment: Wondering if the title could (should?) be: How to be bodek shaatnez?

Comment: Between you and me- it's a hairy business

Comment: @JoshK Can you explain to me as why thats the case?

Comment: It's a play on words, @Avi M, nothing to be concerned about

Comment: You should know not all Shaatnez labs are run the same way, in terms of what they check and so on. Be thoughtful choosing where you learn based on what outcome you think you want.

Comment: “To learn the laws“, I’d suggest just that - learning the laws (Yoreh De’ah beginning at §298); to learn “the practical checking” - it comes with familiarity and experience by knowing where manufactures would typically have mixtures in an article of clothing. Make some calls. Ask around. Google is your friend too.

Answer (score 3):

There is an organization in Lakewood New Jersey that gives a week-long training every once in a while. It is called NCSTAR, WWW.SHATNEZ.N3.NET

I know people from other states that arranged to stay in Lakewood for the week and get trained.

Their contact info is:

(732) 364-7056

SHATNEZHEDQTRS@YESHIVANET.COM

You can read a short article about them [here](https://www.vosizneias.com/14295/2008/02/18/lakewood-nj-classroom-teaches-how-to/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @[user6591](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6591/user6591)'s answer, two additional resources that seem worthwhile exploring:

1) **TorahLive.com** Laws of Shatnez  "[Learn What and How to Check - Torah Live](https://torahlive.com/courses/shatnez-ultimate-divide/)" offers an online course along with a certificate of completion.
Not sure what the cost is, how rigorous it is, or whether said certificate is widely acknowledged.

2) **Yeshivat Pirchei Shoshanim** offers a 6 month [Hilchos Shatnez Course](https://www.shulchanaruch.com/courses/shortcourses/shaatnez/). As their website states:

> There are two levels. One is the general knowledge level where one just receives the Shiurim and Level two requires application and acceptance into the program. Once accepted and completed one will have the right to set up a Shatnez Laboratory in their community.

Seems pretty rigorous (sample shiurim: [here](http://www.shulchanaruch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Shaatnez-Lesson-01.pdf) and [here](http://www.shulchanaruch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Shaatnez-Lesson-02.pdf)), but also not sure how much the course costs.

Comment: I got excited about the online course. But it's not really an actual course. It's informational videos about shatnez aimed at children.

Comment: @user6591 oh interesting- my bad. Why about #2? That also seems to be an online course

Comment: I didn't have a chance to check that out yet:) I'll be back....

Comment: Sorry but that second site says This second level will require one to travel to the Shatnez worldwide headquarters in Lakewood, N.J. USA where one will get a week of intense hands on training and will thereafter have followup as part of the cost of the Program.

I'm pretty sure they are referring to the place I mentioned. Independent of that, I'm not sure how much of a right of passage the first part of the course is.